# The identity element of a group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

We define the process [image]  in  Z. Then, [image]  is a group. In this group,which is the identity element? The correct answer is the element 10. why ?

Comment: Hint: What is $10\cdot b$ in your group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e$ be the identity element. Then by definition, we have for any $a \in \mathbb Z$ that:
$$
a = a * e = a + e - 10
$$
Solving for $e$ using high school algebra, we obtain $e = 10$, as desired.

Comment: thank youu!! Also, which is the inverse element of 13 in the same group ?

Comment: By definition, we want to solve for $x \in \mathbb Z$, where:
$$
10 = e = 13 * x = 13 + x - 10
$$
So what should the inverse be?

Comment: the correct answer is 7. ok, thank you very much !